Webview as overlay in Broadcast Upload extension
I am currently developing a screen broadcasting UIKit application aimed at assisting users in streaming games to social networking platforms. To achieve this goal, I am utilizing the Broadcast Upload Extension. However, I have encountered an issue with adding a UIWebView as an overlay during screen recording. I understand that we need to take a snapshot and retrieve an image to add as an overlay to CMSampleBuffers. However, this approach leads to excessive memory consumption and crashes the extension.
    private func processWriterBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
            
    }

Despite conducting extensive research and multiple attempts, I have not found any documentation addressing this specific requirement. However, I am aware of existing applications such as StreamChamp Streaming App and Prism Live that successfully incorporate this feature.

Given these insights, I am reaching out for suggestions on resolving this issue. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in implementing the code to incorporate a URL as an overlay, similar to the functionality of the StreamChamp app.
Best regards,
